# UITableViewController buttons stick to top during pull to refresh

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, sdk

I am trying to figure out how to have a `UITableView` with a view at the top which scrolls with the table, but when you pull to refresh, the view stays at the top of the screen and the refresh control is below. This is just like the Facebook App with their Status, Photo and Check In buttons.

I can't work out how to do it, any ideas ?

[image: Facebook App 1]
[image: Facebook App 2]

Comment: you should upload images with small size here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Facebook the header isn't part of the table view, it's just a view positioned above the table view. The table view is a subclass of `UIScrollView` so you will receive scroll view delegate methods. You can use these to monitor the scroll view content offset and then change the frames of the header and table views to get the effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

The elements which you add to the `UIScrollView` will scroll along with it. The scroll view is added to the `UIView`. Now if you add additional components to the UIView they wont scroll.